# Two records sharing the same values?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe2, record

I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032793/comparing-records-with-operators) about using records with operators. During testing, I've discovered an anomaly where two instances of this type seem to share the same memory.

The record has an array of Integer...

```
type
  TVersion = record
    Values: array of Integer;
    function Count: Integer;
    class operator implicit(aVersion: TVersion): String;
    class operator implicit(aVersion: String): TVersion;
  end;

class operator TVersion.implicit(aVersion: TVersion): String;
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  Result:= '';
  for X := 0 to Length(aVersion.Values)-1 do begin
    if X > 0 then Result:= Result + '.';
    Result:= Result + IntToStr(aVersion.Values[X]);
  end;
end;

class operator TVersion.implicit(aVersion: String): TVersion;
var
  S, T: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  S:= aVersion + '.';
  SetLength(Result.Values, 0);
  while Length(S) > 0 do begin
    I:= Pos('.', S);
    T:= Copy(S, 1, I-1);
    Delete(S, 1, I);
    SetLength(Result.Values, Length(Result.Values)+1);
    Result.Values[Length(Result.Values)-1]:= StrToIntDef(T, 0);
  end;
end;

function TVersion.Count: Integer;
begin
  Result:= Length(Values);
end;
```

Now I try to implement this...

```
var
  V1, V2: TVersion;
begin
  V1:= '1.2.3.4';
  V2:= V1;
  ShowMessage(V1);
  ShowMessage(V2);
  V2.Values[2]:= 8;
  ShowMessage(V1);
  ShowMessage(V2);
end;
```

I expect that the `V2` should be `1.2.8.4` and `V1` to remain `1.2.3.4`. However, `V1` also changes to `1.2.8.4`.

How do I keep these records independent when I assign them?

Comment: PS - I originally had a typo in my question where it started with "A asked..." I guess that's in relation to something like `ReferQuestion(aAsked: TAskedQuestion);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. A dynamic array variable is a pointer. When you assign a dynamic array variable you take a copy of the *pointer* and increase the reference count. Of course this also happens when you assign compound structures that contain dynamic arrays.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays) covers this:

> If X and Y are variables of the same dynamic-array type, X := Y points X to the same array as Y. (There is no need to allocate memory for X before performing this operation.) Unlike strings and static arrays, copy-on-write is not employed for dynamic arrays, so they are not automatically copied before they are written to.

To get a mental model for this, this of dynamic arrays as being *references* in the same way as classes and interfaces. This is in contrast to simple types (integer, double etc.), strings, records, etc.

The standard way to deal with this is as follows:

1. Make the dynamic array private.
2. Expose the contents of the array through properties.
3. In the element setter, make sure that the reference to the dynamic array is unique.

That last step is the tricky part. Make a dynamic array reference unique by calling `SetLength`:

```
SetLength(arr, Length(arr));
```

One of the promises that `SetLength` makes is that it will always make its first argument be unique.

This has the effect of implementing copy-on-write. To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to implement copy-on-assign because the compiler gives you no hook into the assignment operator.

So the answer to:

> How do I keep these records independent when I assign them?

is that you cannot. You need to use copy-on-write instead.

Comment: As a hurdle, I used `V2:= String(V1);`

Comment: I understand the reason why it happens, but how do I fix this?

Comment: @Jerry I was getting to that. Slow due to having to answer on my Q10

Comment: That assignment operator was essentially what I was looking for :( Improvisations at their best :-)

Comment: @Jerry Well, it's not an "assignment operator". It's the property setter for an element of the array. Slightly different. It would be nice if we could overload assignment.

Comment: I'm just finally getting into this class function stuff... Still have tons to learn

Comment: Copy on write seems to be confusing for many. As you said, if the array is not publicly accessible, there is no harm in copying. But any modifictin of the array must be guarded and at that point, a copy (simply by using `arr := Copy(arr)`, which achieves the same as your `SetLength(...)`) must be made. IOW, that no copy is made on assignment is not a problem. A copy must be made on modification. That way, by controlling access, it is very easy to do your own copy-on-write.

Comment: @Rudy For a large array, the `SetLength` approach is better because it is cheaper. Very often the array will already be unique and using `SetLength` avoids making a copy needlessly.

Comment: @David: you are right. SetLength with the same size only makes a copy when that is necessary (i.e. if the array is not unique), while Copy ALWAYS makes a copy. I just wanted to amend my comment but you beat me to it.

Comment: Fact is that many seem to understand copy-on-write as that a copy is made on assignment. I merely wanted to stress that the copy (or at least uniqueness) must only be made when the data are modified, not earlier. Unlike for strings, the owner of the dynarray is responsible for implementing copy-on-modification. This is best done when the array is encapsulated and every code accessing it checks whether a copy (or uniqueness) is required.

Comment: @Rudy OK. I think I have paragraph in the answer that covers that by pointing out that there are no assign hooks. In terms of COW as an optimisation, yes the copy must happen at modify and not at assign. However, the example here would be fine with copy on assign, were that possible. That's why the emphasis is different. Copy on write is used in my answer for semantic reasons rather than optimisation. Here COW is used to enforce value semantics.

Comment: COW is used to enforce value semantics indeed. But it is exactly there to avoid direct copies when there is no need for them. It is an optimisation mechanism.

Comment: @Rudy No it is not. It can be used as optimisation. Here it is used because it is the only option. Since I don't have the option of copy on assignment, how can this be an optimisation? It is simply the only solution that results in correct semantics. Let us suppose that the copy is cheap, as it is here. And I wanted to avoid the complexity of COW. Please tell me how I would achieve that?